# Did the Two Trees illuminate the whole of Arda or just Valinor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

After the destruction of the Two Lamps (Ormal and Illuin), the Valar created two massive Trees (Laurelin and Telperion) in Valinor and gave them light that was left over from the Lamps that gave Elves who arrived in Valinor a more enhanced power until they were destroyed by Morgoth and Ungoliant some time after.

**Did the light of the Two Trees pass beyond Valinor and light up the whole of Arda, or just illuminate Valinor?**